# Suppose that $X$ is a $p\times n$ matrix, is it always true that $XX^T - n\bar{X}\bar{X}^T$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $X$ is a $p\times n$ matrix, is it always true that $XX^T - n\bar{X}\bar{X}^T$ is always positive definite? Here, $\bar{X}$ is a $p \times 1$ vector of row averages, such that $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, where $X_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$.

From $XX^T - n\bar{X}\bar{X}^T$, I know that $XX^T$ is positive **semi**-definite, but I am not sure how to get the definiteness from here.

Comment: What is yout definition of the sqaure of a column vector? My guess is that you meant to write $v^2 = vv^{\mathsf{T}}$, but I would like you to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, changed it above, thanks!

Comment: And how about if all column vectors are identical so that $X_i = \bar{X}$ for all $i$? I guess that you may need some extra condition on $X$

Comment: I do not have that all column vectors are identical actually, I am envisioning $X$ to be a Normal Random Matrix.

Comment: I checked that $XX^{\mathsf{T}} - n\bar{X}\bar{X}^{\mathsf{T}}$ is positive definite if and only if $\{ X_i - \bar{X} : i = 1, \cdots, n\}$ spans $\Bbb{R}^p$. But I am not sure if there are easier criteria.